# How with open works?

Tags: python-3.x, with-statement

Today I was trying to open a file and build some list from the data of the file. I am using the *with* statement. But I have the following doubt:

If I write the following code:

```
def Preset_wheel_filler(self):
    """
    Complete the Preset_wheel and also apply preset values when one
    preset is selected.
    """
    with open('Preset.txt', 'r') as PresetFile:
        Presets = [line.split()[1:] for line in PresetFile if 'name:'
                   in line.split()]

    with open('Preset.txt', 'r') as PresetFile:
        channel_list = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
        Preset_values = [line.split() for line in PresetFile for
                         y in channel_list if y in line.split()]

    print(len(Preset_values))
```

The length of the last list created is 16. (Which is correct)

Now, if I rearrange the code like this:

```
def Preset_wheel_filler(self):
    """
    Complete the Preset_wheel and also apply preset values when one
    preset is selected.
    """
    with open('Preset.txt', 'r') as PresetFile:
        Presets = [line.split()[1:] for line in PresetFile if 'name:'
                   in line.split()]
        channel_list = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
        Preset_values = [line.split() for line in PresetFile for
                         y in channel_list if y in line.split()]

    print(len(Preset_values))
```

The printed length is 0.

My question is: Why should I write the *with open* statement twice?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files are stream based. Once you read all the data in the file its position pointer is at the end and nothing can be read anymore. You "could" seek to 0 to fix that, but - you have the full line in the first go, simply parse both things from it.

```
PresetFile.seek(0)  # goes back to the beginning of the file.
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects
for details on how to use seek and maybee peek into https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open
again.

Comment: Got it! Really appreciated.